# Rails partials: Trouble finding where to put reference to new method in my partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I'm fairly new to Rails and am trying to figure out how to add a method to the ActiveView class so I can then access a new method from the partials.

Here's some sample code:

```
%li
  =link_to "#{h aim_small.description.shorten} #{"(current aim)" if aim_small.description == current_aim.description}", :action => 'show', :id => aim_small
  .options
    =link_to "edit", :controller => 'aims', :action => 'edit', :id => aim_small
    =link_to "remove", :controller => 'aims', :action => 'destroy', :id => aim_small
```

I want to be able to call the current_aim method in the above partial, but am having trouble getting Ruby to recognize its existance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `current_aim` in de second line is incorrect, you should change it to this

```
=link_to "#{h aim_small.description.shorten} #{current_aim if aim_small.description == current_aim.description}", :action => 'show', :id => aim_small
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the method 'current_aim' into the ApplicationHelper :)